# plotting multiple columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new python and I have two columns in a dataframe that i want to plot against date

```
plt.scatter(thing.date,thing.loc[:,['numbers','more_numbers']])
```

my intuition is the above should work (because matlab allows for this kind of thing), but it doesn't, and I'm not sure why.

Is there away around this?

---

I'm hoping to plot these columns for a sequence of 4 dataframes on the same axes - so i'd like to use a command like the above so I can colour the columns from each data frame to make it distinctive.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to do a loop:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for col in ['numbers', 'more_numbers']:
    ax.scatter(things.date, things[col], label=col)
    # or
    # things.scatter(x='date', y=col, label=col, ax=ax)

plt.show()
```